# What does R1AVH zoning mean in real estate?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, pennsylvania

There are zoning class that are listed as **`R1AVH`, what does that mean?**

E.g. https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/90-S-12th-St-Pittsburgh-PA-15203/2086062520_zpid/

I've tried googling for the term but I can't seem to find an answer to R1AVH.

I guess R1 means "Single-family dwellings" but what is AVH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possibly a Pittsburgh-specific designation and is a combination of **R1A** and **VH**, which are spelled out in section [**902.01.A.1 Residential Zoning Districts**](https://library.municode.com/pa/pittsburgh/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=PIZOCO_TITNINEZOCO_ARTIINES_CH902ZODIGE_902.01ESZODI) of the Pittsburgh code of ordinances.

- R1A = Single-Unit Attached Residential
- VH = Very High-Density

Answer (score 4):

Zoning codes are generally location specific and are defined by local municipalities. In Pittsburg, PA you can look up the zoning for the property by an address using [this interactive map](https://gis.pittsburghpa.gov/pghzoning/). For the property in question it shows zoning as "R1A-VH - SINGLE-UNIT ATTACHED RESIDENTIAL VERY HIGH DENSITY". You can look up the municipal code for specific definitions of each zone.